# How can I register for Amazon MWS through API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I want to integrate Amazon MWS to my e-commerce website. Through which user can post their products on amazon for which I want to call amazon mws api. Can users get register for amazon mws through api call . How?

Answer (score 1):

Is the Integrated Registration Process (IRP) what you're looking for?  I understand that this is an automated method to grant a developer access to an account.

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/how-to-implement-integrated-registration-process-irp-help/26116